# How to create antisniper mechanism swap ERC20?

Tags: solidity, tokens, pancakeswap, binance-smart-chain

When adding a pool of liquidity to a pancake, in the first second the dividend is bought up by the bot and users buy already at an inflated price.
There are ways to counter these bots.

[image: Sniper bots]

However, I can't find a working smart contract Antisnipe.

https://bscscan.com/address/0xf625069dce62dF95b4910f83446954B871F0Fc4f#code

```
interface IAntisnipe {
    function assureCanTransfer(
        address sender,
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) external;
}
```

Proxy: https://bscscan.com/address/0xd64242ca749d03223046397a99026162c1b2a535#code

How to get real code from this contract, which has a function `assureCanTransfer`

```
    function _beforeTokenTransfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal override whenNotPaused {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, amount);
        if (from == address(0) || to == address(0)) return;
        if (!antisnipeDisable && address(antisnipe) != address(0))
            antisnipe.assureCanTransfer(msg.sender, from, to, amount);
    }
```

Could you show me the implementation on Solidity?